# Lining up values to the right

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

if i have some values scattered that i want to line up to the right [image]

Can this be achieved using formulas ,or VBA ?

Thanks

Comment: `Can this be achieved using formulas ,or VBA ?` Formulas→No, VBA→Yes.  I am assuming that you want to do this in place and not in a new set of cells.  If you want to keep the original and do the line up in a new column then Formulas are a "Yes" also.

Comment: Formula: `=CONCAT(A1,B1,C1,D1)`

Comment: Just sort them horizontally.  It will bring them all into one column.

Comment: @FunThomas no need to do each cell with CONCAT: `=CONCAT(A1:D1)`  Concat can take an array or range.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I feel stupid now...

Comment: @FunThomas "old habits die hard".  I too am having some difficulties at time remembering all the new formula and their uses, and tend to fall back on old habits.

Comment: You can achieve this with a formula as well, if you are using **O365** and presently in **Insiders Beta Channel** Version then --> `=TOCOL(A1:D6,3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Align Data

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AlignData()
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        If rCount + cCount = 2 Then Exit Sub ' one cell only
        
        Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Value
        
        Dim cValue As Variant
        Dim r As Long
        Dim sc As Long
        Dim dc As Long
        
        For r = 1 To rCount
            dc = cCount
            For sc = cCount To 1 Step -1
                cValue = Data(r, sc)
                If Len(CStr(cValue)) > 0 Then
                    Data(r, sc) = Empty
                    Data(r, dc) = cValue
                    dc = dc - 1
                End If
            Next sc
        Next r
        
        .Value = Data
        
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Data aligned.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, the macro does exactly what i need